# When I tried change the frame of a mapView, it just disappear

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Here is what I want to do: I have a tableView, in one cell of which there is a mapView. When I click the map, the map will get full screen large. And when I hit back, it will get back to origin size.

Here is the code to enlarge the map and it works fine now:

```
func enlargeMap(){

    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
    DataStruct.ViewingMap = true
    frame = mapView.bounds

    openMapButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"External Filled"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    openMapButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(DetailTableViewController.openInAppleMap), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.minX, self.tableView.frame.minY + self.tableView.contentOffset.y , self.tableView.frame.width, self.tableView.frame.height)
        self.view.addSubview(self.mapView)

    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.addSubview(self.openMapButton)
        self.openMapButton.frame = CGRectMake(self.mapView.frame.minX + 20, self.mapView.frame.maxY - 60, 38, 38)
        self.beforeViewController.navigationItem.title = self.RestaurantName.text!
    }
}
```

Here is the code to close(make it smaller) the map:

func getBackToOriginalSize(){

```
    DataStruct.ViewingMap = false

    openMapButton.removeFromSuperview()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: { () -> Void in

        self.mapView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.tableView.contentSize.height - 249, self.tableView.frame.width, 160)

        }){(Bool) -> Void in
            self.getBacktoLocation(self.initialLocation)
            self.beforeViewController.navigationItem.title = "DinersCode"
}
```

}

I found that I can move the map to wherever I want, but I just can't change the size of it. Otherwise it's gonna to disappear.

Here is a gif showing the problem.

Can anyone give some idea what's wrong?? Thanks a lot!

[problem gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stIt7.gif)

Comment: Actually it worked a month ago, but suddenly it didn't...